# How to run `play` in a 512M vps -- it reports `Could not reserve enough space for object heap`?

Tags: startup, sbt, playframework-2.0

I'm running play2 on a 512M vps.

It can create a new app:

```
play new test
```

But can't start that `test` project:

```
cd test
play
```

It reports such an error:

```
[freewind@289144 test]$ play
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for object heap
Could not create the Java virtual machine.
[freewind@289144 test]$
```

After some research, I found play2 will invoke `play-2.0/framework/build`, and `build` has following settings:

I tried to modify the `play-2.0/play` shell, from:

```
java ${DEBUG_PARAM} -Xms512M -Xmx1536M -Xss1M -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled 
     -XX:MaxPermSize=384M -Dfile.encoding=UTF8 -Dplay.version="${PLAY_VERSION}" 
     -Dsbt.ivy.home=`dirname $0`/../repository -Dplay.home=`dirname $0` 
     -Dsbt.boot.properties=`dirname $0`/sbt/sbt.boot.properties 
     -jar `dirname $0`/sbt/sbt-launch.jar "$@"
```

We can see that the `Xms` is 512M, the vps hasn't enough memory for it.

So I change it to:

```
java ${DEBUG_PARAM} -Xms112M -Xmx300M -Xss1M 
     -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -XX:MaxPermSize=84M -Dfile.encoding=UTF8
     ...
```

This time, the error message is changed:

```
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Cannot create VM thread. Out of system resources.
```

What should I do?

Comment: Actually, play can run in a 512M vps. I found the problem later: The vps I used provided fake memory, it shows 512M, actually is only less than 200M. (The vps is unmanaged and cheap, has no swap, but I'd better not write its name). If you have the same problem, make some tests on vps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I build and develop locally.  I then run "play dist" to create a distribution which contains a start script.  I deploy to my 512MB VPS using [Fabric](http://fabfile.org/) and do not have any memory issues.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you're running the Sun Hotspot VM, run it like this:

```
_JAVA_OPTIONS="-Xmx384m" play <your commands>
```

And you'll get what you need. When the VM launches, it includes the contents of the _JAVA_OPTIONS environment variable along with any other command-line Java options you specify. You'll know it was picked up because you'll see the following message on your console:

> Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xmx384m

The shell command above defines the variable only for execution of the rest of the shell command. If you wanted to make it more durable, you could say something like

```
export _JAVA_OPTIONS="-Xmx384m"
```

and put that in .bash_profile, or .profile, etc.

The _JAVA_OPTIONS environment variable is poorly documented, and I'm not sure how widely it is supported, but I'm pretty sure it works on Linux, BSD* (like Mac OS), and...I don't know what else.

Comment: You can also use `JAVA_OPTS` as in `JAVA_OPTS="-Xms2m -Xmx16m" play start`. Difference is, `JAVA_OPTS` is Play specific, and gets added to or replaces `_JAVA_OPTIONS`. It works on 2.1.4, might not work on earlier versions.

Answer (score 4):

I faced the same issue but I found the reason and the solution.

It is a java parameter in play. I do a simple check:

```
java -Xms512M -Xmx1024M -Xss1M -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -XX:MaxPermSize=256M -version
```

This does not work, but

```
java -Xms512M -Xmx1024M -Xss1M -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled
```

does work! and

```
java -Xms512M -Xmx512M -Xss1M -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -XX:MaxPermSize=256M
```

works too.

You have to modify the `build.bat` as I did: on maximum mem size or change the maximum permanent size.

Answer (score 2):

Another way is to use the following command (it works when you dont use play dist but have the framework installed on the server aswell, maybe it works with the standalone package too but I have not tested it):

```
play "start 6000" -Xms64m -Xmx128m -server
```

the "start 6000" will start the server listening on port 6000.

Answer (score 1):

play stage && target/start -Xmx384m